# How is IObservable<double>.Average supposed to work?

Tags: .net, average, system.reactive

### Update

Looks like Jon Skeet was right (big surprise!) and the issue was with my assumption about the `Average` extension providing a *continuous* average (it doesn't).

For the behavior I'm after, I wrote a simple `ContinuousAverage` extension method, the implementation of which I am including here for the benefit of others who may want something similar:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions {
    private class ContinuousAverager {
            private double _mean;
            private long _count;

        public ContinuousAverager() {
            _mean = 0.0;
            _count = 0L;
        }

        // undecided whether this method needs to be made thread-safe or not
        // seems that ought to be the responsibility of the IObservable (?)
        public double Add(double value) {
            double delta = value - _mean;
            _mean += (delta / (double)(++_count));
            return _mean;
        }
    }

    public static IObservable<double> ContinousAverage(this IObservable<double> source) {
        var averager = new ContinuousAverager();

        return source.Select(x => averager.Add(x));
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of going ahead and doing something like the above for the other obvious candidates as well -- so, `ContinuousCount`, `ContinuousSum`, `ContinuousMin`, `ContinuousMax` ... perhaps `ContinuousVariance` and `ContinuousStandardDeviation` as well? Any thoughts on that?

---

### Original Question

I use [Rx Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) a little bit here and there, and feel I've got the basic ideas down.

Now here's something odd: I was under the impression that if I wrote this:

```
var ticks = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteEventArgs>(MarketDataProvider, "MarketTick");

var bids = ticks
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Quote.HasBid)
    .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Quote.Bid);

var bidsSubscription = bids.Subscribe(
    b => Console.WriteLine("Bid: {0}", b)
);

var avgOfBids = bids.Average();
var avgOfBidsSubscription = avgOfBids.Subscribe(
    b => Console.WriteLine("Avg Bid: {0}", b)
);
```

I would get two `IObservable<double>` objects (`bids` and `avgOfBids`); one would basically be a stream of all the market bids from my `MarketDataProvider`, the other would be a stream of the *average* of these bids.

So something like this:

```
Bid    Avg Bid
1      1
2      1.5
1      1.33
2      1.5
```

It seems that my `avgOfBids` object isn't doing anything. What am I missing? I think I've probably misunderstood what `Average` is actually supposed to do. (This also seems to be the case for all of the aggregate-like extension methods on `IObservable<T>` -- e.g., `Max`, `Count`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregate methods don't provide *rolling* max/min/count/average etc - they provide a *single* value when the original stream completes. So for example, if you change your code to:

```
var avgOfBids = bids.Take(5).Average();
var avgOfBidsSubscription = avgOfBids.Subscribe(
    b => Console.WriteLine("Avg Bid: {0}", b)
);
```

Then once 5 bids have been made, it will display the average of them. The "average" stream will then complete too.

Comment: Jon, do you know of a decent source of documentation for Rx?  I've looked through MSDN and the Rx team's blog to no avail.

Comment: @Pierreten: Nope. I use the CHM files which come with it, and the forum for questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suppose that does make sense; I am with Pierreten in wishing MSDN had more documentation on these methods, though. In any case, I was able to get the behavior I wanted by writing a simple implementation myself. Do you happen to know if something like what I've written (in my updated answer) already exists somewhere? A continuous analytics library, of sorts?

Comment: @Dan: I believe you could get away with just using Scan and Select if you were cunning... make Scan return a tuple of (count, total) and then select total / count.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do ContinousAverage would be to use a .Scan():

```
bids.Scan(new { sum = .0, count = 0 }, 
          (agg, x) => new { sum = agg.sum + x, count = agg.count + 1 })
    .Select(agg => agg.sum / agg.count)
```

Comment: Yep, this is indeed a clever way to get it. Jon Skeet suggested the same thing in one of his comments. I'm still thinking it'd be handy to have a `ContinuousStandardDeviation` method, though, or perhaps something like `ContinuousStatistics` that returns an `IObservable<Statistics>` where `Statistics` is a `struct` including mean, variance, standard deviation, etc.

Comment: @Dan: Take a look at this implementation:  http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2010/01/02/streaming-olap-with-the-reactive-extensions-rx-for-net-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After subscribing to the bids event stream; you've effectively blocked any other observers from subscribing (Subscribe returns an IDisposable.)

You'll have to define another Observable in parallel with ticks, and subscribe to that one to average it.

```
var ticksToAverage = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteEventArgs>(MarketDataProvider, "MarketTick");

 var bidsToAverage = ticksToAverage
      .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Quote.HasBid)
         .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Quote.Bid);


var avgOfBids = bidsToAverage.Average();
var avgOfBidsSubscription = avgOfBids.Subscribe( b => Console.WriteLine("Avg Bid: {0}", b)
                );
```

Comment: Why would subscribing block? I'm willing to admit that Rx regularly confuses me, but I can't see why that would be the case. I believe the problem is entirely different here.

Comment: I was also under the impression that Average provides a running average; based on your answer that seems to be wrong.   As far as blocking, you could very well be correct; since Rx uses regular CLR events under the hood; and multiple parties can subscribe to an event without blocking.

Comment: Looks like Jon's answer was the right one in this case. Thanks for your input, though; I appreciate it!

Comment: FYI, the only part of Rx that uses CLR is `Observable.FromEvent`